# dplyr::summarise render table error

Tags: shiny, dplyr

I have a shiny app where I am just trying to use group by and summarise within a renderTable. The below code works fine in a normal script, but when I try to run it in shiny I get the below error. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

`Error in summarise_impl: Columns`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`, ... cannot have NA as`

```
output$Risk <- renderTable({

    dailyvols <- data.frame(cbind(FrontSwapLegPerf2$`Total Return`-(BackSwapLegPerf2$`Total Return`*HedgeRatios1),
                                  FrontSwapLegPerf2$Residual))
    colnames(dailyvols) <- c("Total_Return","Residual")                      
    dailyvols$bin <- round(dailyvols$Residual)        

 Bins <- group_by(dailyvols, bin ) %>%
          summarise(SD = sd(Total_Return))

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that column `Total_Return` has NAs in it. Use `sd(Total_Return, na.rm = TRUE)` and you will get a result.

Comment: hmm. it appears I am still have the same error once I add na.rm = TRUE

Comment: then it's not a shiny error. Use a breakpoint in `renderTable` to check the error when using `summarise`